# Почему 2 потока работают медленнее чем 480 в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность, x86

Я хочу проверить, как работает AtomicLong в Java и написал для этого небольшой код.
Я ожидал, что увеличение количества потоков больше количества ядер в процессоре должно наоборот замедлить код, однако результаты выполнения показывают противоположное.
[image: Общее время выполнения][image: Среднее время выполнения каждым потоком своей части]

OA - Один объект AtomicLong для всех потоков.
XA - Для каждого потока свой объект AtomicLong.
По оси X количество потоков.
По оси Y количество миллисекунд до завершения работы всеми потоками в гистограмме "Total execution time" и среднее время работы потока в "Average execution time".

Код запускался и через IntellijIDEA, и через терминал (никакой разницы не заметил), OS Windows 10, CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400F CPU @ 2.90GHz.

Вот лямбда Callable выполняемая каждым потоком:

```
private static final long TARGET_FOR_THREAD = TARGET / THREADS_COUNT;

() -> {
                        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                        Result result = new Result(threadName);

                        for (int i = 0; i < QUANTITY_EXECUTIONS; i++) {

                            double dbl = doubles[counter];

                            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            for (int j = 0; j < TARGET_FOR_THREAD; j++) {
                                atomicLong.incrementAndGet();
                                dbl += INCREASE_DOUBLE;
                            }

                            long invokeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                            result.setOrAddInvokeTime(invokeTime);
                            result.setOrAddAtomicLongValue(atomicLong);
                            result.setOrAddDoubleValue(dbl);
                            result.setAtomicLongID(atomicLong);
                        }
                        soutThreadExecutionResult(result);
                        return result;
                    }
```

TARGET = 2_000_000_000

Comment: На самом деле вы тут вряд ли измерили, что хотели, а намерили количество "попугаев" для разных сайд-эффектов, оптимизаций, переходных процессов, латентности, гранулярности вызова получения времени и пр.

Comment: Выполняешь на пуле потоков? Если да, то задачи не конкурируют за врямя процессора, время ожидания в очереди у тебя никак не учитывается, при увеличении числа потоков, уменьшается счётчик TARGET_FOR_THREAD, поэтому потоки делают меньше работы. очевидно, что меньшее кол-во работы будет выполнено за меньшее время.

Comment: Мне кажется просто время не сложилось из-за гонки